# Question on Arithmetic and Geometric Progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

Problem:

> $S_1, S_2, S_3, \ldots ,S_n$ are the sum of $n$ terms of $n$ GPs whose first term is 1 in each case. 
>   
> However, the common ratios $r$ are $1,2, 3, \ldots,n$ respectively.
>   Prove that $$S_1 + S_2 + 2 S_3 + 3 S_4 +\cdots+ (n - 1) S_n = 1^n  + 2^n  + 3^n + \cdots + n^n $$

My attempt:

$$S_1=0$$
$$S_2=(2^n-1)$$
$$2S_3=(3^n-1)$$
$$\vdots$$

$$(n-1)S_n=(n^n-1)$$
$$\Longrightarrow S_1 + S_2 + 2 S_3 + 3 S_4 +\cdots+ (n – 1) S_n =2^n+3^n+4^n+\cdots+n^n - (n-1)$$
Unfortunately I am unable to proceed any further. I would be truly grateful if somebody would please show me how to proceed. Many, many thanks!

Comment: Well, can you tell me , what is the formula for the sum of $n$-tems of a GP?

Comment: How you get that $S_1=0$?

Comment: take $S_1=n , 1=1^n$ the you will get your ans in your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $S_1=n$, not $0$. $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^{n-1}=\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$ is true for $r\not=1$.

We have $S_1=1+1+\cdots+1=n$ (because it has $n$ terms)

For $i\ge 2$, we have
$$S_i=1+i+i^2+\cdots+i^{n-1}=\frac{i^n-1}{i-1}.$$
Hence, we have
$$\begin{align}S_1+\sum_{i=2}^{n}(i-1)S_i&=n+\sum_{i=2}^{n}(i-1)\cdot\frac{i^n-1}{i-1}\\&=n+\sum_{i=2}^{n}(i^n-1)\\&=n-(n-2+1)+\sum_{i=2}^{n}i^n\end{align}$$